# Couldn't map over a object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an API response returning 14 categories and I need to map them and render accordingly. I called the API using useEffect and the categories were stored into **categories** variable using setCategories (setState). But once I map them, I get *categories.map is not a function.*

**code :**

```
function BottomContainer() {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await axios.get(
        ""
      );
      // console.log(response.data.menus);
      setCategories(response.data.categories);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  // console.log(categories[0].en_description);

  return (
    <div className="mt-16">
      <MenuItems />

      {categories.map((category) => (
        <div>
          <p className="text-3xl font-semibold ml-4 mt-5">Popular</p>
          <FoodList name="California Roll" price="4.99" />
          <FoodList name="California Roll" price="4.99" />
          <FoodList name="California Roll" price="4.99" />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Error on console:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: categories.map is not a function
```

Comment: You map over an array not an object. Change this `useState([])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store the API results in an array not an object if you want to map over them.

```
const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the result of the API request in an array so that you can iterate using the map

```
 const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
```

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-yalow-knm7y?file=/src/BottomContainer.js)

```
export default function BottomContainer() {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await axios.get(
        ""
      );
      setCategories(response.data.categories);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);


  return (
    <div className="mt-16">
      {
        categories.map((category) => {
          return <div key={category.id}>{category.en_description}</div>;
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply map to object entries:

```js
Object.entries(categories).map(console.log)
```